# React Native error kept popping up on my device when I initialize firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native

The error is as follows:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
throwOnInvalidObjectType
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7436:6
reconcileChildFibers
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8470:31
reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8635:8
reconcileChildren
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8603:6
updateHostRoot
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8931:26
beginWork
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9586:30
performUnitOfWork
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12924:25
workLoop
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12953:43
renderRoot
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12996:17
performWorkOnRoot
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13632:34
performWork
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13545:26
performSyncWork
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13506:16
requestWork
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13392:6
scheduleWorkImpl
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13259:24
scheduleWork
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13207:28
scheduleRootUpdate
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13930:17
_updateContainerAtExpirationTime
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13966:6
updateContainer
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13991:8
render
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14726:35
renderApplication
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:49:21
run
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:102:10
runApplication
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:194:26
__callFunction
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:351:47
<unknown>
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:116:26
__guardSafe
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:6
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    C:\reactnative\auth\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:115:17
```

I made the header a reusable component which i can use for other projects.

App.js
this contains the firebase bucket that brings about the error

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyBQu8oX851Q53RL_5UylJPI1cCU203s2Us',
            authDomain: 'authentication-163ed.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://authentication-163ed.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'authentication-163ed',
            storageBucket: 'authentication-163ed.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '623306210919'
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
            <Header headerText="Authentication" />
            <LoginForm />
            </View>
            );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Header.js

```
// Import a library to create a component
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

//Create a component
const Header = (props) => {
    const  { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
        </View>
        );

};
const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 60,
        paddingTop: 15,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.9,
        elevation: 2,
        position: 'relative'
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
};

//Make the component available
export { Header };
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    state = { text: '' };
    render() {
        return(
                <Card>
                    <CardSection>
                        <TextInput 
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })} />
                    </CardSection>
                    <CardSection />
                    <CardSection>
                        <Button>Log in</Button>
                    </CardSection>
                </Card>
            );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

The error disappears immediately I remove the firebase.initializeApp() api from my code. but its important its linked with firebase as it will authenticate users for the app.

Comment: Can you add the code of your Header and LoginForm components?

Comment: I have updated the code with the Header and LoginForm components as requested

Comment: Can you upload the full error? It will give more details.

Comment: I have uploaded the full error from the device.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find the bug here. Try to check that you are importing your components from the right locations of your project.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when I was following "The Complete React Native and Redux course" on Udemy, which looks remarkably similar to your code! One of the Q&A for lecture 71 covered this same problem as well and the solution was to replace:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

in App.js with:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
```

This kicks up an eslint error with the my configuration but it runs properly. It was noted as an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/871) when v 5.0.4 of the Firebase SDK was released.